# Cannot create new version of existing self-signed and CA signed certificate on Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure-keyvault

I'm new to Azure KeyVault. I'm trying to create a new version of self-signed  and CA signed certificates  and first I got a message saying it was successfully created but while refreshing the page, the new version doesn't show up. Another attempt on adding new version shows me this error

RAW ERROR
A new key vault certificate can not be created or imported while a pending key vault certificate's status is inProgress

I have given it a day for the new version of the certificate to show but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it may take some time to create a new version of self-signed certificate:

[image]

When the states is complete, your new version certificate will show up:

[image]

Version list:

[image]

---

It seems to be a temporary error. I suggest you create a new certificate and try again. If the error persists, you may contact the Azure support team. They would be able to help you further by checking the resource.

Comment: Thanks! Self signed certificate appeared after awhile. For the CA signed certificate, once I clicked on Certificate Operation, there was "Merge Signed Request awaiting" for  new signed certificate to be merged. Once I merged crt I was able to see the new version.